# Datagrid.AddingNewItem Not Performing Action in View Model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro's message action syntax to call my `AddSampleWithType` method in my view model when the datagrid's `AddingNewItem` event is raised.  When a user presses the Enter key in the datagrid and the datagrid begins to create a new row, I want create a new item in my `Samples` BindableCollection using the `Sample` class' constructor that requires that the `SampleType` be passed in.

Here is my view's DataGrid XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="Samples" SelectedIndex="{Binding SamplesIndex}" Margin="5" Grid.Row="3"
                 BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  cal:Message.Attach="[Event AddingNewItem] = [Action AddSampleWithType($eventArgs)]">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sample Names" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}" >
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

And the important code in the view model:

```
public void AddSampleWithType(EventArgs e)
{
    AddingNewItemEventArgs newItemEventArg = (AddingNewItemEventArgs)e;
    newItemEventArg.NewItem = new Sample(selectedSampleType, "New Sample", SessionSettings.Instance.UserID);
}
```

I put a breakpoint at the first statement in the `AddSampleWithType` method, but the program never goes there; the method is never called.

Is there something wrong with my cal:Message.Attach statement that I do not see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try putting `AddingNewItemEventArgs` as the parameter of the Method? since the method "signature" has to match the events signature... simply passing EventArgs isn't enough.. CM understands that especially since you are using $eventArgs special.

When I have added an event I didn't know the signature for it by heart I would add the method using the designer to "code behind" first copy and paste the parts I need to my viewmodel method in question.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.addingnewitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I tried both the generic event arts and the specific one for AddingNewItem. Neither worked.

Comment: So mocked this up to see if there was something missing... It fired right off when "starting" to add the new row.  Now, is this datagrid buried in some other control (nested)?  Is there a possibility that the datagrid doesn't have a datacontext?  Do you have CM debugging active?  `LogManager.GetLog = type => new DebugLog(type);` put in the bootstrapper constructor before `Initialize();` assuming you don't have or never used it.  Run project from VS in debug mode, console output will have CM debug information included...

Comment: Here's the solution.  I had to use the full Interaction.Trigger syntax listed in the Caliburn.Micro documentation.  This includes using the cal:Parameter statement for the $eventArgs special value.  When I ran the application, it called the AddSampleWithType method before it created a new row.  Oddly, after this test, I reverted back to the shorthand Message.Attach syntax and the AddSampleWithType method was called.  It behaved like the full syntax was needed to "prime the pump."  Thanks, mvermef, for your help.